# helm & projectile: how to remove a project from projectile

Tags: emacs, emacs-helm

I have several projects defined, and when I run `C-c p p`, it will list all of the projects. Now I don't want a project and I have deleted the .projectile file under that project, but it still shows up. How do I delete it?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The function `projectile-remove-known-project` prompts for a project to forget about. `projectile-remove-current-project-from-known-projects` removes the active project.

Known projects are stored in the file `~/.emacs.d/projectile-bookmarks.eld`.

Comment: Thanks! Addendum for Spacemacs users: I found the file under `~/.emacs.d/.cache/projectile-bookmarks.eld`.

Comment: The order of the entries of the list in this file changes all the time and really clutters up your git working tree, so I would not recommend this as a persistent mechanism for storing known projects as configuration!

Comment: On Doom Emacs, I found ~/.emacs.d/.local/cache/projectile.projects

Comment: Is it possible to change path for the ``projectile-bookmarks.eld` ?

Comment: @alper, that should probably be a separate question but it looks like you can modify the variable `projectile-known-projects-file`.

Comment: @Chris please see https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/64159/how-to-change-projectile-bookmarks-eld-saving-path